# docker containers do not start - network was found but has incorrect label com.docker.compose.network set to ""

Tags: docker

The messages are warning... but i cannot get the endpoints... any ideas ?

```
level=warning msg="The \"H\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
At line:1 char:1
+ docker-compose up -d
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (time="2023-07-1... blank string.":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
level=warning msg="The \"H\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
level=warning msg="The \"H\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
level=warning msg="a network with name tac_default exists but was not created by compose.\nSet `external: true` to use an existing 
network"
network tac_default was found but has incorrect label com.docker.compose.network set to ""
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the error in the text along with the image?

Comment: Hi ,  i added additional information. thanks

Comment: Are you able to share some of your .env file and remove sensitive information? Is it possible you are using quotes in there where perhaps you shouldnt?

Answer (score 6):

You may encounter a similar issue when the container is spun up using the `up.ps1` script, and subsequently, when attempting to run `docker compose down` followed by `docker compose up`, you encounter an error. This issue is likely caused by the network interface created by `up.ps1` not being properly utilized during the execution of `docker compose up`.

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. Run `docker network ls` to list all the available networks.
2. Run `docker network prune` to remove all networks.
   Note: This command will delete all unused networks on your system.
3. If you want to remove specific network use the command `docker network rm <network Id> <space> <network Id>` to remove the problematic network.
4. Once the network pruning is complete, run `docker compose up -d` to start the containers.

After following these steps, the issue should be resolved, and `docker compose up` should work fine.

Reference:

1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/
2. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_ls/

Comment: This solved the error for me, thank you!